# Footer overlaps content when content is 100%

Tags: html, css, footer, overlap, overlapping

What I want is that my .content_pro always sticks to the top of the footer, what resolution your screen is. But when I say height: 100% it gets under my footer. I'. struggling with this for a few hours but it won't work. Here is my HTML & CSS:

HTML:

```
    <!--Begin Content-->     
<div id="content_pro">
    <div id="pro_menu">
        <div class="grey"><img class="pro_img" src="images/bannehof.jpg"><a href="subpages/bannehof.html" target="targetframe" class="pro_title">Bannehof</a><br /><br />Deuren c.a. 750</div>
        <div class="white"><img class="pro_img" src="images/casaconfetti.jpg"><a href="subpages/casaconfetti.html" target="targetframe" class="pro_title">Casa Confetti</a><br /><br />Deuren c.a. 850</div>
        <div class="grey"><img class="pro_img" src="images/citymax.jpg"><a href="subpages/citymax.html" target="targetframe" class="pro_title">Citymax</a><br /><br />Deuren c.a. 2200</div>
        <div class="white"><img class="pro_img" src="images/nielsborghplaats.jpg"><a href="subpages/nielsborghplaats.html" target="targetframe" class="pro_title">Niels Borghplaat</a><br /><br />Deuren c.a. 15</div>
        <div class="grey"><img class="pro_img" src="images/ronssehof.jpg"><a href="subpages/ronssehof.html" target="targetframe" class="pro_title">Ronssehof</a><br /><br />Deuren c.a. 2500</div>
        <div class="white"><img class="pro_img" src="images/rusthoeve.jpg"><a href="subpages/rusthoeve.html" target="targetframe" class="pro_title">Rusthoeve</a><br /><br />Deuren c.a. 255</div>
        <div class="grey"><img class="pro_img" src="images/westerbeek.jpg"><a href="subpages/westerbeek.html" target="targetframe" class="pro_title">Westerbeek</a><br /><br />Deuren c.a. 350</div>
    </div>
        <iframe class="pro_subpage" src="subpages/bannehof.html" name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
</div>
<!--End Content-->
</div>    
<!--Begin Footer-->
    <footer>
    <div id="foo_container">
        <div id="foo_navs">
            <div id="foo_nav_1">
                &raquo <a href="../index.html">Home</a><br />
                &raquo <a href="../deuren">Deuren</a><br />
                &raquo <a href="../hangensluitwerk">Hang en Sluitwerk</a><br />
                &raquo <a href="#">Projectbasis</a><br />
            </div>
            <div class="foo_sep"></div>         
            <div id="foo_nav_2">
                &raquo <a href="../particulier">Particulier</a><br />
                &raquo <a href="../recenties">Recenties</a><br />
                &raquo <a href="../fotos">Foto's</a><br />
                &raquo <a href="../werkwijze">Werkwijze</a>
            </div>
            <div class="foo_sep"></div>
            <div id="foo_nav_3">
                &raquo <a href="../contact">Contact</a>
            </div>
            <div class="foo_sep"></div>
            <div id="copyright">
                Copyright &copy;<br /> <a href="http://www.grafisch-centrum.nl" target="_blank">Grafisch Centrum Etten-Leur</a> 2014
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="foo_keurmerk">
            <a href="http://www.inbraakproef.nl" target="_blank"><img class="foo_inbraak" src="../images/pkvw-logo.png" /></a>
            <a href="../images/VCA07042011Roos.tiff"><img class="foo_vca" src="../images/vca1.png"/></a>
            <div class="foo_sep_keurmerk">
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
<!--End Footer-->
```

CSS:

```
* {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:arial;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

    #content_pro {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9;
    height: 100%;
}

#pro_menu {
    height: 84%;
    width: 380px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 80px 0px 25px 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
}

footer, .push {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eb691e;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all want you remove this step from your css

```
* {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:arial;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

You can leave only those but sometimes it extra rules and no need to use it

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

font-family you need to use in body tag - like this

```
body {
    font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

As for your question. Here is an example how to stick footer to the bottom (as I correctly understanding what you trying to achieve)

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="w1">sdfsdfsd</div>
</div>
<footer id="footer">ssdfsdfs</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.w1 {padding-bottom:50px /*footer height*/;}
#footer {
    height: 50px;
    margin-top: -50px; /*equal to footer height */
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly then Something like this will work I guess. Just added padding .

Here is **fiddle**  http://jsfiddle.net/9cKTH/

```
* {
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    font-family:arial;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

    #content_pro {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 9;
    height: 100%;
    padding-bottom:50px;
}

#pro_menu {
    height: 84%;
    width: 380px;
    position: absolute;
    float: left;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin: 80px 0px 25px 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    z-index: 999;
}

footer, .push {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eb691e;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 10;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This is what you wanted??

Comment: Not exactly.. I'm sorry if you don't understand what I mean, I'm not good in asking things this way. But what I want is that the bottom of the content always sticks to the top of the footer. So if you make your browser window bigger or smaller the footer allready stays always at the bottom, but I want the content to move with it. And I see that my html and css is a bit ruined by the things I tried.